# Using AWK need to format the output

Tags: awk

I have a file having :(colon) as deli metre as shown below where in that file having some comments where starting with ##

```
##No sync
no_sync:start:Async:SingleChainSdo:end:tile_dfx.sdc_ch_pcie_bot_lft_STAC.I_JTAG1500BC_SWB_0.I_SWB_Shift.I_ShTDR[0].Qreg:IP_WRCK
yes_sync:start:Async:SingleChainSdo:end:tile_dfx.sdc_ch_pcie_bot_lft_STAC.I_stac_pipeline_Wso.I_PIPELINE_POSEDGE.Qreg:IP_WRCK

  ##TDR will be static during functional operation
Rev:start:MTAP_Wrck:tile_dfx.dft_clk_cntl_Cpl_SMNCLK.clk_cntl_tdr.reg_CLK_CNTL.DFT_TDRUPDATEREG.q[3:1]:end:tile_dfx.dft_clk_cntl_Cpl_SMNCLK.dft_gater_aon:SMNCLK

Note: In column $4 we have the value "tile_dfx.dft_clk_cntl_Cpl_SMNCLK.clk_cntl_tdr.reg_CLK_CNTL.DFT_TDRUPDATEREG.q[3:1]" where :(colon) is available here need to ignore colon in []..In some values column $5 also it will repeat
```

I have tried this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F: '/^[^#]/ {print "adc report item -status waived -scheme" " "$1, "-from" " ""{"$4"}", "-to" " ""{"$6"}", "-tx_clock" " "$3, "-rx_clock" " "$7 }' vio.s
```

Output what I got:

```
adc report item -status waived -scheme no_sync -from {SingleChainSdo} -to {tile_dfx.sdc_ch_pcie_bot_lft_STAC.I_JTAG1500BC_SWB_0.I_SWB_Shift.I_ShTDR[0].Qreg} -tx_clock Async -rx_clock IP_WRCK
adc report item -status waived -scheme yes_sync -from {SingleChainSdo} -to {tile_dfx.sdc_ch_pcie_bot_lft_STAC.I_stac_pipeline_Wso.I_PIPELINE_POSEDGE.Qreg} -tx_clock Async -rx_clock IP_WRCK
adc report item -status waived -scheme Rev -from {tile_dfx.dft_clk_cntl_Cpl_SMNCLK.clk_cntl_tdr.reg_CLK_CNTL.DFT_TDRUPDATEREG.q[3} -to {end} -tx_clock MTAP_Wrck -rx_clock tile_dfx.dft_clk_cntl_Cpl_SMNCLK.dft_gater_aon
```

Actual output:

```
adc report item -status waived -scheme no_sync -from {SingleChainSdo} -to {tile_dfx.sdc_ch_pcie_bot_lft_STAC.I_JTAG1500BC_SWB_0.I_SWB_Shift.I_ShTDR[0].Qreg} -tx_clock Async -rx_clock IP_WRCK
adc report item -status waived -scheme yes_sync -from {SingleChainSdo} -to {tile_dfx.sdc_ch_pcie_bot_lft_STAC.I_stac_pipeline_Wso.I_PIPELINE_POSEDGE.Qreg} -tx_clock Async -rx_clock IP_WRCK
adc report item -status waived -scheme Rev -from {tile_dfx.dft_clk_cntl_Cpl_SMNCLK.clk_cntl_tdr.reg_CLK_CNTL.DFT_TDRUPDATEREG.q[3:1]} -to {tile_dfx.dft_clk_cntl_Cpl_SMNCLK.dft_gater_aon} -tx_clock MTAP_Wrck -rx_clock SMNCLK
```

The main issue is how to ignore the :(colon) delimetre in between []

Comment: Well, a `:` is either a delimeter or it is not.  What you can do is before handing the data to `awk`, look for the `:` embedded in square braces and replace it with something else, and replace it back when composing your output.  Or you can check the final character of the value of `$4` and if it is not a `]`, append a colon and the value of `$5`.  But since you're using later fields than the fourth, the first option would probably be easier than also prodecturally offsetting all of your field references.

Comment: @DopeGhoti thanks for your idea...it will help me thank you so much.